# verificar la existencia de caracter por caracter de una cadena con un parrafo en C

Tags: c

Como puedo almacenar una lista de palabras y que luego al introducir un párrafo por teclado el programa me pueda verificar si ese parrafo(introducido por teclado) contiene las letras de las palabras almacenadas anteriormente.

ejemplo

palabras almacenadas:

```
sol, luz, ...
```

por teclado:

```
"hola soy programador"
```

palabra sol

```
existe la S, existe la O y existe la L dentro del párrafo.
```

y asi sucesivamente con las otras palabras almacenadas.

espero haberme explicado correctamente por el momento he pensado en alamcenar las palabras en vectores pero no se si sea correcto y muchas gracias de antemano.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
   char pal1[2][10]= {"sol","agua,""luz"};

   char nombre[100]; 
   printf("Escribe una frase: "); 
   fgets(nombre, 100, stdin);

  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te entendí bien, tan sólo necesitas saber si todas las letras de una palabra existen en una frase; de ser así el código es bastante sencillo:

```
unsigned existe(const char *palabra, const char *frase)
{
    unsigned resultado = 0u;
    unsigned letras = strlen(palabra);

    for (const char *buscar = palabra; *buscar; ++buscar)
    {
        unsigned encontrada = 0;

        for (const char *en = frase; *en && !encontrada; ++en)
        {
            encontrada = *buscar == *en ? 1 : 0;
        }

        resultado += encontrada;
    }

    return (resultado == letras) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

La función `existe` devuelve `1` si todas las letras de `palabra` están presentes en `frase` y `0` en caso contrario. Para ello recorre letra a letra de `palabra` y las compara con todas las letras de `frase`, por cada coincidencia para el bucle y suma 1 al contador `resultado`, si al finalizar la función este contador es igual que la longitud de la palabra recibida: entonces todas las letras están presentes en la frase:

```
int main()
{
    char pal1[3][10] = {"sol", "agua", "luz"};
    char nombre[100] = {};
    printf("Escribe una frase: "); 
    fgets(nombre, 100, stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        printf("'%s' existe en '%s'? %d\n", pal1[i], nombre, existe(pal1[i], nombre));

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior, si se le introduce la frase *hola soy un programador*, muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 'sol' existe en 'hola soy un programador'? 1
> 'agua' existe en 'hola soy un programador'? 1
> 'luz' existe en 'hola soy un programador'? 0
> ```

Ten en cuenta que el algoritmo propuesto no tiene en cuenta repetición de letras, es decir: `"amalgama"` contaría como existente en `"hola soy un programador"` pese a que la palabra tiene cuatro `'a'` y la frase tiene tan sólo tres.

Comment: La Palabra 'Luz' no debería imprimirla ya que la Z no existe en "Hola soy un programador". sin embargo si la imprime.

Comment: La palabra luz al no existir en la frase devuelve 0 en la salida; el resto devuelven 1 al llamar a la función existe. Es decir, en base al resultado de la función puedes determinar si se debe mostrar la palabra o no… sabiendo programar me imagino que sabrás cómo examinar el retorno de una función para hacer una acción determinada ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el código de la función. En este caso utilice el método strchr de string.h que lo que hace es buscar un caracter dentro de un string,devolviendo el puntero de la primera ocurrencia.

Se va a recorrer la cadena palabra mientras el puntero ptr sea distinto a NULL y no sea el fin de la cadena (este seria cuando palabra[i] sea igual a '\0'). En caso de que haya un caracter que no exista en la frase, el ciclo terminará y el resultado res seria 0 (falso), de lo contrario, res sera 1 (true).

```
int existe(const char* frase, const char* palabra){
int i=0,res=1;
char* ptr=strchr(frase,palabra[i]);
while(ptr!=NULL&& palabra[i]){
    i++;
    ptr=strchr(frase,palabra[i]);   
}
if(ptr==NULL)
    res=0;
return res;
```

}

Espero que te sirva. Cualquier consulta que tengas no dudes en decirmela.